# Determining how IE was refreshed

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, refresh

A c# application we have, acts differently when the browser (IE) is refreshed using F5 or by clicking the URL and pressing Enter. Is there a way to determine how the page was refreshed?

Comment: You mean you have a WebBrowser control in the application, or what is the situation exactly?

Comment: It's an Asp.Net webforms application where session variables are used. For some unknown reason, as I haven't wrote the application, the session variables sometimes are lost. The behaviour is different when you press F5 or Enter in the URL line, so I want to determine which refresh method was used.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in ASP.NET web forms, check the IsPostBack member in the Page_Load to see if you are loading page for first time (url enter) or second time or more (F5).

Comment: `IsPostback` won't be true for an F5 refresh, it's only true if the page was loaded as a result of a form being posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use referrer to see if page is referred by some other page or opened by broswer

Comment: Isn't both cases (F5 or Enter on the URL line) considered as opened by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a direct, easy way to test for this.  The main difference between clicking on "go" and hitting F5 is that "go" will always perform an HTTP GET, and F5 will repeat the last HTTP request, which may have been an HTTP GET, or it may have been an HTTP POST.

This might manifest itself in the following way - you may have a button being seemingly clicked twice (because you clicked it, then hit F5 after the page reloaded).

Having said all of this, consider:

- If you are experiencing an issue with behaviour based on "go" vs F5, you are almost certainly doing something wrong or "illegal" in the application.
- Attempting to interpret the exact details of what the user did in their browser is the wrong approach; the HTTP protocol describes how a browser interacts with your server, trying to figure out what lies behind that black box is wrong.  You need to design your application so that it is "well behaved" for common HTTP scenarios, such as this.

Comment: There are further technical details about the differences between types of refresh here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx

Comment: @EricLaw - thanks for the info, I realise I was simplifying quite a lot there :)